# How can I refactor to reduce no of lines

Tags: javascript, refactoring

'If' and 'else if' share almost similar code expect on which the forEach is called. Tried using a function to place same lines of code in them. But have trouble calling them (maybe because it is a  window.setMinMax function, instead of regular function.

Whereas 'else' part has slight different code. How can I refactor to reduce the no of lines. Thank you.

```
window.setMinMax = function (min, max, seriesName, clickedYAxis) 
{
var FruitSeries = ["Apple", "Orange", "Grape"];
var NutSeries = ["Almond", "Walnut"];
let chartIndex = Highcharts.charts.length - 1;

if (FruitSeries.includes(seriesName)) {
    FruitSeries.forEach(function (valueSeriesName) {
        Highcharts.charts[chartIndex].series.forEach(function (value, index) {
            if (Highcharts.charts[chartIndex].series[index].name == valueSeriesName) {
                var indexForYAxis = Highcharts.charts[chartIndex].series[index].yAxis.index;
                Highcharts.charts[chartIndex].yAxis[indexForYAxis].setExtremes(min, max);                   
            }
        });
    });
}
else if (NutSeries.includes(seriesName)) {
    NutSeries.forEach(function (valueSeriesName) {
        Highcharts.charts[chartIndex].series.forEach(function (value, index) {
            if (Highcharts.charts[chartIndex].series[index].name == valueSeriesName) {
                var indexForYAxis = Highcharts.charts[chartIndex].series[index].yAxis.index;
                Highcharts.charts[chartIndex].yAxis[indexForYAxis].setExtremes(min, max);
                
            }
        });
    });
}
else {
    Highcharts.charts[chartIndex].series.forEach(function (value, index) {
        if (Highcharts.charts[chartIndex].series[index].name == seriesName && Highcharts.charts[chartIndex].series[index].yAxis.userOptions.ChartIndex == clickedYAxis) {
            var indexForYAxis = Highcharts.charts[chartIndex].series[index].yAxis.index;
            Highcharts.charts[chartIndex].yAxis[indexForYAxis].setExtremes(min, max);
            
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Use one more loop

Comment: "*Tried using a function to place same lines of code in them*" - can you [edit] your question to show us that attempt, please? It's a good approach, but we'lll need to see your code to tell you what went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of strategies to refactor this code. First

1. There is a lot of unnecessary looping in this code. Step back from the code and realize the loops are looking for a single element.
2. The `forEach` functions with an `if` check is the same as a find or filter. I suggest using the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function to find what you need from the array, then act on it accordingly.
3. Utilize a closure to reduce repetition.
4. Read and understand [flattening arrow code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/).

```javascript
window.setMinMax = function(min, max, seriesName, clickedYAxis) {
  const FruitSeries = ["Apple", "Orange", "Grape"];
  const NutSeries = ["Almond", "Walnut"];
  let chartIndex = Highcharts.charts.length - 1;

  function setExtremes(seriesName) {
    let series = Highcharts.charts[chartIndex].series.find(s => s.name === seriesName);
    var indexForYAxis = series.yAxis.index;
    Highcharts.charts[chartIndex].yAxis[indexForYAxis].setExtremes(min, max);
  }

  if (FruitSeries.includes(seriesName)) {
    for (let fruit of FruitSeries) {
      setExtremes(fruit);
    }
  } else if (NutSeries.includes(seriesName)) {
    for (let nut of NutSeries) {
      setExtremes(nut);
    }
  } else {
    let series = Highcharts.charts[chartIndex].series.find(s => s.name === seriesName);
    if (series && series.yAxis.userOptions.ChartIndex == clickedYAxis) {
      setExtremes(seriesName);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Very informative. Thank you.